# How to make Cells in UITableView as Hyperlinks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I would like to make the Cells in a UITableView Hyperlinked.

Comment: Be more specific as to what you want. Do you want tapping on the cell to go deeper into a navigation hierarchy, or do you want some text in the cell to say, open up a web browser? It's impossible to know what you're asking here, and this question could be closed if you don't provide more details.

Comment: Got you frustrated there with my question! I just want to click on a cell and then open a web browser. It doesn't necessarily need to be a hyperlink. I'm new to XCode, so excuse my ignorance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom `UITableViewCell` and add a `UITextView` that detects hyperlinks.